# Regex matching sortcode

Tags: regex, pcre

I'm trying to match a UK bank sort code (nothing complex, just three pairs of digits, optionally separated by hyphens). I thought that I could just try and match the first hyphen and then use backreferencing to check if the value I'm matching was using hyphens at all.

```
/^\d{2}(-)?\d{2}\1\d{2}$/
```

Which should match against

```
12-34-56
123456
```

But not against

```
12-3456
1234-56
```

Which is fine and works fine — in JavaScript.

When I use a PCRE engine (e.g. PHP) the regex doesn't match as I'd expect. I've used a different regex to avoid this but I'd still like to know what's going on?

Can I use some internal dark magic along the lines of `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` to be able to use the optional backreference?

Comment: Could you please show how you use it in PHP?

Comment: @sp00m: `$ php -r "var_dump(preg_match('/^\d{2}(-)?\d{2}\1\d{2}$/', '123456'));"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript follows the ECMA standard specifications.

> According to the official ECMA standard, a backreference to a non-participating capturing group must successfully match nothing just like a backreference to a participating group that captured nothing does. ([source](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref2.html))

Here, in `/^\d{2}(-)?\d{2}\1\d{2}$/`, we have an ***optional*** capturing group that can match a hyphen. JavaScript regex engine "consumes" empty texts in optional groups for them to be later accessible via backreferences. This problem is closely connected with the [Backreferences to Failed Groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref2.html). E.g. `((q)?b\2)` will match `b` in JavaScript, but it won't match in PCRE.

So, a way out is using an **obligatory** capture group with an empty alternative ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/sE4iP5/2)):

```
^\d{2}(-|)\d{2}\1\d{2}$
        ^^
```

Also, you can move the `?` quantifier to the hyphen itself ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/sE4iP5/3)):

```
^\d{2}(-?)\d{2}\1\d{2}$
```

Comment: Well, I linked to the regular-expressions.info, where the problem of failed capture groups is dwelt upon in a quite comprehensive way, IMHO. I also think that in your current situation you can just make the hyphen rather than the whole Group 1 optional. In other cases, you can use the empty alternative solution, it will look less cumbersome.

Answer (score 3):

You can change your regex to match it:

```
^\d{2}(-|)\d{2}\1\d{2}$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lB0zQ1/1)

Changing `(-)?` to `(-|)` makes sure that we capture either hyphen or an empty string in group #1.

**Code:**

**New RegEx:**

```
preg_match('/^\d{2}(-|)\d{2}\1\d{2}$/', '123456', $m);
print_r($m);
Array
(
    [0] => 123456
    [1] =>
)
```

**Older Regex:**

```
preg_match('/^\d{2}(-)?\d{2}\1\d{2}$/', '123456', $m);
print_r($m);
Array
(
)
```